# Lego Mindstorm - r3ptar - why case not work

Tags: algorithm, lego-mindstorms

I try programing a Lego Mindstorm - r3ptar. On Youtube etc. are many examples, but I don't know why my own program not work - if I try it seperated all works fine, but together not.

Schema of IO:

[image]

Working code for move and change a status if Infrared sensor hit:

[image]

If I want add open a mouth (the motor "D" rotaion one time), go back for 1 sec (the motor "B") and close the mouth (again motor "D" rotation onetime back) - works only to open mouth (1st step) and next steps dont' work.

[image]

Can you please explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake - incorrect parameter.

If someone find this problem, I send here a solution

[image]